# How to create a new registry.pol file using c#

Tags: c#, windows, registry, group-policy

Actually I am using this statement to create registry.pol file...

```
using(File.CreateText(@"C:\User\Desktop\Registry.file"))
{

}

using(streamWriter writer=new streamWriter(@"C:\User\Desktop\Registry.file"))
{
    writer.write("PReg    ");
}
```

registry.pol file is created but it is not the same as original registry.pol file created by windows operating system.

Answer (score -1):

You have to explain what exactly should be there in file which is missing.